# Regex Tweak: Remove Brackets

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have the following script:

```
    $(".Text").contents().each(function () {
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text()
            .replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, '<span class="IT_Symbol" style="display:inline;border: 1px solid blue;">$&</span>')
        );
    });
```

It finds anything between square brackets and wraps it with a class. The element style is so i can see it working, as this script is triggered by a doubleclick. Currently it finds everything between square brackets including the brackets themselves. If possible, i'd like to remove the brackets, but keep what's between.

Comment: @ianace If you're going to edit code, please don't turn it into illegal Javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing with `$&`, which is the whole matched text.  If you replace with `$1` instead, this only matches the first group, which is `([^\]]*)`, and therefore excludes the surrounding brackets.

```
$(".Text").contents().each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, '<span class="IT_Symbol" style="display:inline;border: 1px solid blue;">$1</span>'));
});
```